# Feasibility of SQLCLR Trigger or Stored Procedure for Audit Trail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sqlclr

Disclaimer: I am unable to implement this properly in the application, as the application I'm working on doesn't do data access in a consistent way, and refactoring effort would be too great for the scope of the project and coming deadline.

How would I go with implementing a SQLCLR Trigger for Audit Trail? I would like it to be as simple as possible, *and as easy to remove and replace with proper implementation* later as possible.

I'm planning to write my audit to a single table (the database is not very write heavy), having columns like:

- Timestamp (`datetime`) - when the change happened?
- Username (`varchar`) - who made the change?
- AffectedTableName (`varchar`) - which table has been affected?
- AffectedRowKey (`varchar`) - this will be either a simple or compound key like (`Id=42`, `A=4,B=2`)
- OperationType (`char(1)`) - either `I`, `U` or `D` for insert, update and delete respectively.
- InsertedXml (`xml`) - xml-serialized row (`SELECT * FROM INSERTED FOR XML AUTO`)
- DeletedXml(`xml`) - xml-serialized row (`SELECT * FROM DELETED FOR XML AUTO`)

I'm planning to query and resolve this data to a user-readable form in the application. I'm planning to implement this as a database trigger, written using SQLCLR. I can see 2 possible approaches:

- Implement this entirely as SqlTrigger method:
- Implement this as a SqlProcedure method taking parameters:

  - schemaName
  - tableName
  - insertedXml
  - deletedXml

I will appreciate any constructive criticism and suggestions. My limitation is that I have to implement the audit at the database level using triggers, and I want it to be as maintainable (read: removable and replacable) as possible. Also ideally, I don't want to have hundreds of triggers with exactly the same body, in case I have to modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using a variation of this script to create audit triggers from some of my projects for awhile now with great results:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/

Comment: move the `@sql` just outside the while loop and replace it with variables for both insert and delete, then exicute the `@sql` only once after the while loop, using your insert and delete variables like your schema above.  sorry, but i don't have time for more than this little hint...  good luck.

Answer (score 2):

There is a serious restriction in SQLCLR triggers that will prevent you from implementing your audit triggers in SQLCLR: you can not find which parent object that was changed from inside a SQLCLR trigger. i.e. if you have a single SQLCLR trigger routine registered to multiple tables, you can not find which table got updated/inserted into/deleted from. At first sight @@procID may look usefull, however when called from inside a SQLCLR trigger, @@procid returns the same value, no matter which table was affected. I have searched the internet and experimented a lot and I have not found a solution. I have found more people having the same issue. Some of the messages date back as far as 2006.

I have created a feature request with Microsoft on Microsoft Connect. Please log in and press the UP arrow to get it implemented so you actually can use a SQLCLR trigger for your purpose: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/768358/a-sqlclr-trigger-should-be-given-the-parent-object-in-the-sqltriggercontext